# how to proxypass or redirect the URL on the basis of HTTP request method in apache?

Tags: apache, http, nginx

some my modules in my application have moved to different microservices. There are two webservices with same URL, one is GET and other is PUT. I need to proxypass the GET request to one server and PUT to another.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ProxyPass` cannot occur within `<If>` section, you can try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =PUT
RewriteRule ^ http://put.backend.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET
RewriteRule ^ http://get.backend.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```